# asp.net mvc migration from vs 2008 to vs2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to open my vs 2008 solution in vs 2010 beta 2.  it converted the solution file and brings in the unit test project but it can't seem to bring in the main project.  it kicks off the vs conversion wizard and says that it completed successfully but the project doesn't show up.

has anyone seen this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [ASP.NET MVC project converter](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Comment: I used this on a project yesterday and it worked awesome. Just make sure that you open the solution in VS2010 afterwards, my solution still opened in 2008. At the same time tho, I hadn't opened it with VS2010 yet either, so it may not be an issue